# Cannot extract Facebook picture url from json graph object

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am grabbing info from Facebook's API about a certain user, using the **/user_id/picture** call, and I var_dump the response and see this:

```
var_dump($graphObject);
```

which gives me the response:

```
object(Facebook\GraphObject)#6 (1) { ["backingData":protected]=> object(stdClass)#8 (2) {   ["url"]=> string(112) "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xap1/t1.0-1/p200x200/115634790309_n.jpg" ["is_silhouette"]=> bool(false) } }
```

And as silly as it is, I can't figure out how to get that **"url"** string into a variable. I am new to this all, but I thought something would work like:

```
graphObject->url;
```

And I have tried a bunch of other things, can anyone help?

Comment: Does `$graphObject->url` work? If not what error do you get?

Comment: This question may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541431/reading-data-from-facebook-graphobject

Comment: WizKid: No, that just gives me an empty string.

Comment: Brandon Gano: Unfortunately, I don't think that getProperty thing works with calls to /me/picture, I have tried that with getProperty('url') and whatnot, I just get errors. I think that's for objects cast as GraphUsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get `$graphObject`, you can convert it into an array so you can access the objects in it, as follows:

```
// convert to array
$graphObject = $graphObject->asArray();

// echo URL
echo $graphObject['url'];
```